# Adding start token while generating with MT5

Tags: python, pytorch, multilingual, huggingface-transformers, nlg

I've a specific use case for generating text using **mT5** model provided by **huggingface**. I need to be able to control the language in which text is generated. I tried adding prefixes to encoder input but the model is always generating text in English. Is there a way to add a prefix to decoder input so that I can use the decoder prefix to control the language of generated text. I am using `model.generate()` function to generate text.